# Adjust PDF options for PhantomJS

Tags: pdf, phantomjs

I use [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) for PDF generation.

This is my command:

```
./phantomjs rasterize.js <someurl> test.pdf
```

It generates pdf file but:

1. The PDF looks nothing like the original website
2. I can't set the page orientation
3. Also is there any other options I can use for pdf generation?

The following change to [rasterize.js](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/rasterize.js) also doesn't seem to work:

```
{ format: system.args[3], orientation: 'Letter', margin: '1cm' }
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Rasterize.js](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/rasterize.js) is a very basic example of screen capture. There are some default values in this example that you can change to your needs.

- [page.viewportSize](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/viewport-size.html)

Simulates the size of the window like in a traditional browser. In rasterize.js, it's `{ width: 600, height: 600 }` ; not a common resolution and you may need to change this.

- [page.paperSize](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/paper-size.html)

Defines the size of the web page when rendered as a PDF. There are two modes : Manual (given a width and a height) or automatic (given a format). Do not hesitate to read the [webpage documentation](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/) and the [wiki page](http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html).

In your case, `orientation: 'Letter'` is **invalid**.
Supported formats are 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'Legal', 'Letter', 'Tabloid'.
Supported orientation are 'portrait' and 'landscape'.

Take a look at the source code and change it to your needs !